# Flat URL Rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to shorten my following URL

From

```
 www.domain.com/index_1.php?var=value
 www.domain.com/index_2.php?name=value
```

To

```
 www.domain.com/value
 www.domain.com/name/value
```

what i really what is,

```
 www.domian.com                    // This should reach index_1.php
 www.domain.com/value              // This should reach index_1.php
 www.domain.com/name               // This should reach index_2.php
 www.domain.com/name/value         // This should reach index_2.php
 www.domain.com/name/              // The last slash should be omitted and redirect to "www.domain.com/name"
```

The "value" range may contains [ 0-9 ][ A-Z ][ a-z ][ - ] [ _ ]

I have tried following .htaccess code,

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (^name?$)|(^name/([^/]+)/?$) /index_2.php?name=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/][^(name)]+)/?$ /index_1.php?var=$1 [L]
```

when i type

```
 www.domian.com                    // It Works.
 www.domain.com/value              // It shows "404 Page Not Found".
 www.domain.com/name               // It works.
 www.domain.com/name/value         // It works.
 www.domain.com/name/              // It shows "404 Page Not Found".
```

if it can be done using PHP, please Answer.

Comment: `www.domain.com/value`  and `www.domain.com/name`  seem to have the same regex. you need something so we can distinguish them from each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between **www.domain.com/name** and **www.domain.com/value**.

otherwise, you can done this by using PHP.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For www.domain.com/value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]

# For www.domain.com/name/value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index_2.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

In index.php:

```
if(isset($_GET["var"])) {
  $value = $_GET["var"];
  if($value == "name"){
    include"index_2.php";  
  }else{
    include"index_1.php";
  }
}else{
  include"index_1.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For www.domain.com/value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index_1.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]

# For www.domain.com/name/value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index_2.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `www.domain.com/value`  should point to `index_1.php` and `www.domain.com/name` should point to `index_2.php`. Your rules fail at that!

Comment: Hope you saw inconsistency in OP. Read first part where it clearly writes **`From

 www.domain.com/index_1.php?var=value
 www.domain.com/index_2.php?name=value`**

Comment: I saw that, that's why I posted a comment on OP. BTW, It seems my down-vote is locked !

Comment: @anubhava "www.domain.com/value" - it works, "www.domain.com/name/value" - it works. but "www.domain.com/name" - it goes to index_1.php

Comment: Hope you understood the discussion here and a comment below your question. How is `www.domain.com/name` different from `www.domain.com/value` for matching?